# Setting the state isn't updating the state right away in the following React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm listening to `keypress` in a React component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [keys, setKeys] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeypress = (event: any) => {
      if (event.key !== "]" && event.key !== "[" && event.key !== "Enter") {
        setKeys([...keys, event.key]);
        console.log(keys)
        // if you pressed, say, `d`, this should log `['d']`,
        // but it logs `[]` instead. 
      }

      // do something with keys
    };

    document.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeypress);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keypress", handleKeypress);
    };
  }, [keys]);

  return (
    <div>
      {keys.map((key: string, idx) => (
        <li key={idx}>{key}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Something strange happens. `console.log(keys)` will log an empty array the first time you press a key ... but that key will show in the JSX.

Why is this? And how to change the code so that `console.log(keys)` doesn't log an empty array the first time you press a key? **I want to use `keys` as soon as it changes.**

Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-props-on-react-root-component-forked-bjqsxe?file=/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` by default simply does one thing, it sets the new state and cause a re-render to the function.

It is asynchronous in nature so by default, methods running after it usually **run**.

When you call `setKeys`, you trigger a re-render of your component, which will call again this function. However, the `console.log(keys)` inside the function still references the first value returned by `useState`, which is your original value (or the last one).

If you want to print it, you can do it by using the `console.log` outside of the `useEffect`.

Comment: So if I want to use `keys` as soon as it changes, I have to do it outside `useEffect`?

Comment: You can use it outside the useEffect to see the change.

Comment: @alexchenco or just put the value in a local variable before setting the state: `const newKeys = [...keys, event.key]; setKeys(newKeys); console.log(newKeys);`